# Rails how to create a test for openid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I'm new to Ruby (Rails) but following the RailsCast tutorial (#68) could add OpenID login to an application.
Now I'd like to create a test (**Test::Unit**), I read some about mocks and stubs, but I'm not pretty sure how should I proceed.

This is how session controller looks:

```
def create
  if using_open_id?
    open_id_authentication(params[:openid_url])
  ...
  end
end

protected
def open_id_authentication(openid_url)    
  authenticate_with_open_id(...) do |result, identity_url, registration|
    if result.successful?
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

I created a simple test, but couldn't test the block inside 'authenticate_with_open_id'.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you looking to make these tests as functional (controller) tests in Rails?

Comment: Yes,similar to these: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html

Answer (score 0):

Within a controller test you can override one of the methods on the controller like this:

```
def @controller.some_method
  ..
end
```

so you can stub out the `authenticate_with_open_id` method using this technique.

Now lets say you want to write a test for the scenario "a new user is created for successful Open ID login with an unrecognised identity URL" we need to stub out `authenticate_with_open_id` with a method that will yield the appropriate parameters to the block. e.g.

```
class SuccessfulResult
  def successful?
    true
  end
end

def @controller.authenticate_with_open_id(url, options)
    yield SuccessfulResult.new, "NEW_IDENTITY", {'nickname' => 'testuser', 'email' => 'testuser@example.org' }
end
```

You will also need `using_open_id?` to return `true` and you can do this either by stubbing or by passing the required parameters in the request.

You can then assert that an extra user has been added to the database in the usual way.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I have a doubt. I use the instance @controller, but when I tried to override the method, as you said, I got "NoMethodError: protected method `authenticate_with_open_id'". When I see the coverage it doesn't enter that block. If it's necessary, I copy the code

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Is there a way to simulate openid provider response, and test inside that block?

Answer (score 0):

The trick @mikej describes works for me, if you wrap it in a `setup` block for the test like this

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  #wrap in a setup block
  setup do
    def @controller.current_user
      User.first
    end
  end
```